# binomial confidence intervals using a sin link

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I am studying binomial confidence intervals and have encountered a problem when using the sin link, which I think is the same as the arcsin method.

I am using 2 successes ($x = 2$) in 50 trials ($n = 50$).  When I analyze those data with a computer program and the sin link I obtain the following beta estimates:

```
p = x / n = -1.1680805
SE = 0.1414214

lower 95% CI = -1.4452664
upper 95% CI = -0.8908946
```

and the following real estimates:

```
p = 0.0400000
SE = 0.0277128

lower 95% CI = 0.0100254
upper 95% CI = 0.1463468
```

I can obtain most of the estimates above by hand, but I cannot convert the beta estimates for the confidence intervals into the real estimates.  Below I show what I have so far using R code:

```
x <-  2
n <- 50

p.beta <- asin(((x / n) * 2) - 1)
p.real <- (sin(1 * -1.1680805) + 1)/2

SE.beta <- 2 * sqrt(.25/n)
SE.real <- (((x/n) * ((n-x)/n)) / n)^0.5

lci.beta <- asin(((x / n) * 2) - 1) - 1.96 * SE.beta
uci.beta <- asin(((x / n) * 2) - 1) + 1.96 * SE.beta
```

Several attempts suggest the real confidence estimates should be:

```
lower 95% confidence interval = 0.003934274
upper 95% confidence interval = 0.1111827
```

For example:

```
(sin(1 * -1.4452664) + 1)/2
(sin(1 * -0.8908946) + 1)/2

sin(asin(sqrt(p)) - 0.5*1.96/sqrt(n))^2
sin(asin(sqrt(p)) + 0.5*1.96/sqrt(n))^2

g.p   <- 2 * asin( sqrt(x/n)  )
l.g.p <- g.p - 1.96 / sqrt(n)
u.g.p <- g.p + 1.96 / sqrt(n)
(sin(l.g.p / 2))^2
(sin(u.g.p / 2))^2
```

The MKmisc package returns:

```
library(MKmisc)
binomCI(x, n, conf.level = 0.95, method = "arcsine")

# [1] 0.006300929 0.121891908
```

using the following R code:

```
conf.level <- 0.95
alpha <- 1 - conf.level
kappa <- qnorm(1-alpha/2)
p.tilde <- (x + 0.375)/(n + 0.75)
est <- p.tilde
CI.lower <- sin(asin(sqrt(p.tilde)) - 0.5*kappa/sqrt(n))^2
CI.upper <- sin(asin(sqrt(p.tilde)) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt(n))^2
```

I have also tried the following equations found in various articles or on various webpages:

```
sin(asin(sqrt( (x        ) /  n      )) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt(  n      ))^2
sin(asin(sqrt( (x+0.5    ) /  n      )) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt(  n      ))^2
sin(asin(sqrt( (x+0.5+3/8) / (n+3/4) )) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt( (n+1/2) ))^2
sin(asin(sqrt( (x    +3/8) / (n+3/4) )) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt( (n+1/2) ))^2
sin(asin(sqrt( (x    +3/8) / (n+3/4) )) + 0.5*kappa/sqrt( (n    ) ))^2
```

None of these approaches above return estimates of:

```
lower 95% CI = 0.0100254
upper 95% CI = 0.1463468
```

I can obtain the real estimates above by hand using the logit approach, and the `MKmisc` package in R also returns those same estimates, where I think the minor differences are due to the `MKmisc` package using `qnorm(0.975)`, not 1.96 for the critical z value:

```
library(MKmisc)
binomCI(x, n, conf.level = 0.95, method = "logit")

# [1] 0.01002561 0.14634358
```

Should I expect the sin (or arcsin approach) to return the same real confidence interval estimates as the logit approach?  Perhaps I am mistaken in thinking that the software that returned the estimates at the very top was converting the beta estimates into the real estimates.  Perhaps the software used the sin link for the beta estimates, but another approach for the real estimates.

Thank you for any advice on what I am doing wrong when converting the CI beta estimates to real estimates of (0.0100254, 0.1463468), and on what the real confidence interval estimates should be when using the sin or arcsin approach.